# phpgraphlib dark image with php 8.2 -> error handeling

Tags: php, gd, phpgraphlib

I have worked multiple years with the PHP-Library chart generator.
I have made hundreds of charts.

I have made the upgrade with my server to PHP8.2 and guess?
The library doesn't want to work anymore.

Somebody brilliant to help me (us, I'm not alone)

I have tried hours to get the script working and also the error handling, but I can get only receiving a black screen.

Even tips of how I can receive error messages is a good help.

[text](https://github.com/jeroenst/phpgraphlib)

[text](https://github.com/jeroenst/phpgraphlib/blob/master/phpgraphlib.php)

I have changed a lot of the settings from false to true or inverse.

I have also tried to include the library directly on the example page but no different result and no error messages.

On the phpinfo page is the gd library working.
I have basic script that work with the GD library

```
    protected $data_set_count = 0;
    protected $data_min = 0;
    protected $data_max = 0;
    protected $data_count = 0;
    protected $bool_data = false;
    protected $bool_bars_generate = true;
    protected $bool_all_negative = false;
    protected $bool_all_positive = false;
    protected $bool_gradient = false;
    protected $bool_user_data_range = false;
    protected $all_zero_data = false;
    protected $bool_gradient_colors_found = array();
    protected $bool_y_axis_setup = false;
    protected $bool_x_axis_setup = false;
    protected $x_axis_value_interval_counter = 0;
```

Comment: That library has had no commits for 10 years, it's not really reasonable to expect it to run on PHP 8.2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.